# Unit test a TypeScript void function with sinon

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, sinon, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VS Code extension and currently I am in the process of doing unit tests. I am complete new to unit testing and I am quite lost on how I should go about unit testing a void function.

```
export const getChecklistItems = async (id: number): Promise<any> => {
  const checklistItems: ChecklistItem[] = [];
  const items: any[] = await getItemsFromUrl(`path_to_url/{id}`);

  items.map((item) => checklistItems.push(new ChecklistItem(item.checklist_items_id, item.checklist_items_content)));

  return checklistItems;
};

export const onSelectInsertComment = async (id: number): Promise<void> => {
  const editor: TextEditor | undefined = window.activeTextEditor;
  const items: any[] = await getChecklistItems(id);

  items.reverse(); // Workaround to output comments in correct numerical order inside the TextEditor

  if (!editor) {
    window.showWarningMessage('No editors are open in you workspace');
  } else {
    items.forEach((item) => {
      editor?.insertSnippet(new SnippetString(`$LINE_COMMENT ${item.label}\n`));
    });

    window.showInformationMessage('Great. Checklist items have been inserted');
  }
};
```

I am using mocha, chai and sinon for my unit tests. I am trying to use a spy to check whether `getCheckListItems(id)` is called when `onSelectInsertComment(id)` is called. One the the things I tried is the following:

```
describe('#onSelectInsertComment', () => {
  it('should be resolved', () => {
    const id = 1;
    const spy = sinon.spy(getChecklistItems);
    spy.withArgs(id);

    onSelectInsertComment(id);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
  });
});
```

The result is:  `AssertError: expected getChecklistItems to be called once but was called 0 times`.

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate it if I was pointed into the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

- I do not know if this works for VSCode extension, but this works for normal typescript project with sinon.
- For the example: I assume that both *getChecklistItems* and *onSelectInsertComment* are in the same file: util.ts.

In your test, rather than use this import:

```
import { getChecklistItems, onSelectInsertComment } from './util';
```

Use this:

```
import * as util from './util';
```

And change your test code to:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as util from './util';

describe('#onSelectInsertComment', () => {
  it('should be resolved', () => {
    const id = 1;
    const spy = sinon.spy(util, 'getChecklistItems');
    spy.withArgs(id);

    util.onSelectInsertComment(id);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
  });
});
```

**Why?**

Because in your original code, you use sinon spy to wrap your function *getChecklistItems*, but function *onSelectInsertComment* has already defined and not use the spy defined, but use the original *getChecklistItems*. You can check references [1](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/).

**References**

1. [Sinon How to Stub Dependency](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/)
2. [Sinon Spy Method Signature](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#creating-spies-sinonspy-method-signatures)